# SoapException Server was unable to process request on ASMX webservice in MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, exception

I'm getting an exception when trying to access an .asmx webservice within a MVC site.  I've tried numerous things like updating the web reference within the console application and building another quick app to test, but can't get passed this issue.  If I pull the URL out of the svc variable, I can browse to it directly.

### Exception Details

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
>   occurred   Message=Server was unable
>   to process request. ---> Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: uriString
>   Source=System.Web.Services   Actor="" 
>   Lang=""   Node=""   Role=""
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream
>   responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)
>          at ClarityIntegration.SendTrackerDataToClarity()
>   in [REDACTED].Reference.cs:line 78
>          at [REDACTED].Program.Main(String[] args)
>   in [REDACTED].Program.cs:line 33
>   InnerException:

#### CONSOLE APP CODE

```
var svc = new TrackerClarityService.ClarityIntegration()
    {
        Url = url,
        Credentials =
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain")
    };
svc.SendTrackerDataToClarity();
svc.Dispose();
```

#### Issue Resolved

The exception was coming out of the Web Service itself. There were some global variables not being initialized directly through the .asmx call that were being initialized by the application itself.

Some simple checks on variables within the Web Service and setting what needs to be set have fixed up the issue.

Comment: Does this work in the console application? If not, the problem is definitely not related to `asp.net` or `asp.net-mvc` and those tags doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Comment: Darrin - It's all a single solution at this point, so I'm testing the Web Service within my console application and this is where the issue is right now.  I have no clue if it's a web service issue or not right now.

Comment: The error is actually related to the Web Service, not the console application.  The `asp.net-mvc` and `asp.net` tags are very relevant to this issue.

Comment: @RSolberg, so you are able to successfully invoke your web service from the console application. Also if the error is related to the web service the two tags are not relevant. The `web-services` tag is relevant though.

Comment: @Darin: no, hence showing the exception from the console app trying to invoke the webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue Resolved

The exception was coming out of the Web Service itself. There were some global variables not being initialized directly through the .asmx call that were being initialized by the application itself.

Some simple checks on variables within the Web Service and setting what needs to be set have fixed up the issue.

Comment: I get this issue but i don't understand "Some simple checks on variables within the Web Service and setting what needs to be set have fixed up the issue". Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

If using basic auth, this has solved my issues in the past:

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
nc.Domain = "domain"
nc.UserName = "user"
nc.Password = "pwd"

Uri uri = new Uri(svc.Url);
ICredentials credentials = nc.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
svc.Credentials = credentials;
```

Answer (score -1):

Captain here, this is the message when a WebReference has been instantiated, but has no URL defined or the given URL is null, and a method ist called. The origin of an empty URL could be a missing value in a app/web.config file.

Comment: What do you mean "Captain"?